# Easiest Way Of Copying a Row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

what's the easiest way of to clone a row with a different ID in MySQL.

For example:

#### Products

```
product_id  name  price
------------------------
1           a     10
2           b     15
```

It looks like weird, but I need to clone product with `id = 1`. So the table will look like:

#### Products

```
product_id  name  price
------------------------
1           a     10
2           b     15
3           a     10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use <strike>subqueries</strike>:

```
   INSERT INTO 
          donation (name,price) 
   SELECT name,price
     FROM donation 
    WHERE product_id = 1
```

Comment: It's not a subquery -- pretty much all SQL supports using a `SELECT` in an `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO Products (name, price) VALUES ((SELECT name FROM Products WHERE product_id = 1), (SELECT price FROM Products WHERE product_id = 2));

Comment: ^ That's assuming that product_id is a pk that autonumbers

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Products (name, price)
VALUES 
((SELECT name, price 
    FROM Products  
   WHERE product_id = 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone a row with a single SQL statement and can't or don't want to list all the values but there is a primary key you can use:

```
INSERT INTO Products
 SELECT *
  FROM Products
  WHERE product_id = 1
 UNION ALL
  SELECT *
   FROM Products
   WHERE product_id = 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_id=(SELECT MAX(product_id)+1 FROM Products);
```

This tries to insert two copies of the row into the databse and when the first row insert fails due to a duplicate product_id it uses `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to update the existing row in the table to the next available product_id, which leaves the original product_id available for when the second row is inserted.